# Update label foreground color with a variable in real-time

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not having much luck researching this particular task. I'd like to update the foreground color of a text based on whether a number is negative or positive. If the number is negative, it displays in red text. If it's positive, it displays in green.

I'm checking for whether it's negative or not by comparing two variables. If **total** is greater than or equal to **minimum** then it is a positive number and vice versa. It's probably confusing but if you have a **total** of 30 but the **minimum** is 35, then **myvar** is -5.

Putting if statements above the label will obviously only work the first time (when you start the program)

```
if total.get() >= minimum.get():
    Label(root, textvariable=myvar, fg="green")
if total.get() < minimum.get(): # or an else statement here
    Label(root, textvariable=myvar, fg="red")
```

I've also tried defining the label and running a function to configure the foreground color but I don't think I have the syntax quite right or I'm skipping too many steps for this approach. I honestly don't feel I need something elaborate as I just want to update one thing.

```
test_label.configure(foreground="green") #or test_label.config(fg="green")?
```

Right now I'm wondering if I can use a variable (similar to updating textvariable within a label) but I haven't been successful.

```
my_fg = tk.StringVar()
my_fg.set("green") #otherwise the game won't open

Label(root, textvariable=myvar, fg=my_fg.get())

def change_fg():
    if total.get() >= minimum.get():
        my_fg.set("green")
    else:
        my_fg.set("red")
```

This last example doesn't return any errors but it doesn't work either. Does someone know the correct syntax/approach to this? Especially a straight-forward/simple way if possible.

And just in case this information helps or matters, I use buttons to increase and decrease both the total and minimum variables and the change_fg() function in this example would actually just be part of the functions I already have for those buttons. (with the assumption I'm able to do it this way)

Comment: You called `my_fg.get()` *once*, when your Label was being created.  This retrieved the var's value at that time, `"green"`.  It did NOT magically set up any ongoing connection with the var.  Only a few widget options have functionality like that, `textvariable=` for example.  For anything else, you have to reconfigure the widget directly: `my_label.config(fg="red")` perhaps.

Comment: I'm aware of this. My point was that I'm wondering if I'm missing something to be able to use something like textvariable. And I tried the latter as you can see in the middle of my post `test_label.configure(foreground="green") #or test_label.config(fg="green")?` but it gives me an error "test_label has no attribute fg"

Comment: Your `test_label` must have been something other than a Label.

Comment: Sorry this is the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'` and my test_label is a label..
`test_label = Label(root, textvariable=extra, bg=bg_clr).grid(row=6, column=16)`

Comment: No, it's `None` - the return value of the `.grid()` method.  You have to do that as a separate statement if you want to keep a reference to the widget itself.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's probably that then. My mistake